# How can i fix CheckAarMetadataWorkAction error in my java Android project?

Tags: java, gradle

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
I have this error, my gradle has the latest version. How can i fix this?

I tried to upgrade gradle version but it doesnt work

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem ?